# Pricing default risk in cryptos

Tags: risk-management, credit-risk, value-at-risk

I'm looking to figure out how to price "insurance" against a counter-party defaulting in an OTC cryptocurrency transaction. I think the first measure would be to calculate VaR? I'm planning on modeling bitcoin using a stochastic process and calibrating it using historical data. I'm not quite sure which model to use for bitcoin. I've seen some papers use a GARCH model. 
In general, am I approaching this correctly? Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail of how the OTC product is structured? Is this cash settled or physical delivery? I don't think VaR is a bad way to model it but you need to be wary of the liquidity risk (hence why I ask if it is cash settled or physical delivery)

Comment: It's physically settled. There is leverage involved so each counter-party only needs to provide initial margin. In case a counter-party becomes insolvent, there should be insurance purchased to cover the shortfall. I'm trying to price that insurance.

Comment: This sounds like a CDS contract. See if these are helpful: https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/25?topic=mdls and http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dbrigo/cdsmktfor.pdf My background is not in credit risk modeling so sorry if you are looking for something more detailed.

Comment: This sounds like CVA (credit value adjustment) if not on a specific instrument

Comment: GARCH could serve as a building block but, by itself, it is too well-behaved. Not suitable for Bitcoin. At the very least, as a proxy for Bitcoin dynamics you should use [jump-diffusion](http://www.stanfordphd.com/Jump-diffusion_Process.html) with stochastic volatility effects. Those volatility effects could be GARCH-inspired but that is not necessarily the best specification.